# To highlight the first list-item value as default on page load in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have 2 components: `1)contact` `2)display`.

`contact` component is used to display list-of contacts  as in below image:

[image]

Another component 'display', I have placed it on right side of the `contact` component like this:

[image]

Now on `changing/clicking` contacts from the list(i,e in contact component). I am displaying that particular contact data(i,e email,gender...)  on the right side component(i,e `display` component ) as shown in the 2nd image.

**Now the issue is:**

- I want to highlight the 1st contact by default.
- And the 1st highlighted contact data(i,e email,gender...) as to be displayed on the right side (i,e on display component) **like in 2nd image**.

> **contact** component CODE

**HTML**

```
<mat-selection-list>
   <mat-list-option [ngClass]="{selected :  currentContact && contact.fullName == currentContact.fullName}"  *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
    <a mat-list-item (click)="onSelect(contact)"><img src="{{contact?.pictureUrl}}" > <span>{{ contact?.fullName }}</span> </a>
   </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

**SCSS**

```
.selected {
  background-color:blue;
 }
.selected span{
  color:red;
 }
```

**TS**

```
import {Component ,EventEmitter ,Input ,Output, ViewChildfrom 
 '@angular/core';  
import { IContact } from 'src/app/models/app.models';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-contact',
 templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./contact.component.scss'],
})

export class ContactComponent {

@Input()
  public contacts:  IContact[] ;
@Output() public select: EventEmitter<{}> = new EventEmitter(); 

 public currentContact: IContact;

public ngOnInit(): void {
 if (this.contacts && this.contacts.length > 0) {
   this.currentContact = this.contacts[0];
   this.select.emit(this.currentContact);
  }
}

public onSelect(contact: IContact): void {
  this.currentContact = contact; 
  this.select.emit(contact); 
 }

}
```

> **display** component CODE

**HTML**

```
 <div>
  <tr>
      <td>Email </td>
      <td>{{contact?.eMailAddresses}} </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Gender</td>
      <td>{{contact?.gender}} </td>
  </tr>
 </div>
```

**TS**

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input , Output, ViewChild} from 
 '@angular/core';  
import { IContact } from 'src/app/models/app.models';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-display',
 templateUrl: './display.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./display.component.scss'],
})

export class DisplayComponent {

 @Input()
  public contact: IContact;

}
```

Stackblitz **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-xnblnv?file=app/details/details.component.html)**

Comment: does you emit inside ngOnInit works ? if not can you try `ngAfterViewInit` . put up a stackblitz to show your issue .

Comment: emit inside ngOnInit works is working fine, I can see the changes means on clicking next contacts i am able see their information(i,e email, gender) on display component.

Comment: emit inside `ngOnInit` working fine then i don't see a issue . maybe something trivial your missing put up a sample.

Comment: Means you need an `stackblitz` link??

Comment: yeah thats right

Comment: Okay i will give it shortly.

Comment: I have given the stackblitz DEMO, Please see it.

Comment: Content are little changed because in the **stackblitz** i have given an dummy `API`

Comment: ok let me take a look, from what i see as expected emit inside ngOnInit doesn't fire because contacts are undefined .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184790/discussion-between-prashanth-gh-and-super-cool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding `ngOnChanges` to keep an track on contacts as on ngInint `contacts` not yet loaded.

**Code:**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, SimpleChanges, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) { 
  if (this.contacts && this.contacts.length > 0) { 
     this.currentContact = this.contacts[0]; 
     this.select.emit(this.currentContact); 
    } 
 }
```